# Numba - is it possible to do absolute sum without nan faster?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I have a slightly modified example from numba official doc as follows:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def do_sum(A, lb, ub):
    n = len(A)
    acc = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        a = 0.0 if np.isnan(A[i]) else A[i]
        acc += abs(max(min(a, ub[i]), lb[i]))
    return acc
```

Basically, the task is to do absolute bounded sums over a numpy array, which could potentially have `np.nan`. `A`, `lb` and `ub` are all `1d` arrays with the same length. The length are typically in the range of thousands or tens of thousands. And, the function are expected to be called millions of times - that's why I want to optimize it.

Since `A` may contain `np.nan`, it seems that I cannot use `@njit(fastmath=True)`. However, when `A` does not contain `np.nan`, my benchmarking results showed that using `@njit(fastmath=True)` is significantly faster than `@njit`.

My question is that is there some sweet spots in between such that I can make the code work with `fastmath` and get speedup over the `do_sum` implementation above?

Or indeed, whatever approaches/methods can make `do_sum` faster would be very welcome.

For simplicity, we can assume `lb` and `ub` do not contain `nan` values. But if the solution can handle them as well, would be better.

(By the way, this code example is very similar as the example which illustrates `parallel=True` in official numba doc, but when I tried adding `parallel=True` in `do_sum` above, I got significant slow down. Not sure why it is the case.)

Comment: so the requirement also covers `lb` and `ub` to not contain `nan` values?

Comment: ```lb``` and ```ub``` do not contain ```nan``` values.

Comment: Could you pre-process the array and set all nans to zero?

Comment: @SimonLundberg  it is slower than the current implementation. what I want is a potentially faster way of implementing do_sum.

Comment: Have you considered just passing the specific fasthmath flags expect the NaN one? https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fast-math-flags so, see the example here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#fastmath

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not exactly sure about how can I apply it to my case?

Comment: What's producing the NaNs in the first place that you need to later remove them?

Comment: Part of NaNs comes from dynamic source data and another part comes from upstream math/stats processing.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of tests, what worked was parallelization

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def do_sum2(A, lb, ub):
    n = len(A)
    fraction = n // 32
    acc = 0.0
    for j in nb.prange(32):
        acc_local = 0.0
        for i in range(j*fraction, min((j+1)*fraction, n)):
            a = 0.0 if np.isnan(A[i]) else A[i]
            acc += abs(max(min(a, ub[i]), lb[i]))
        acc += acc_local
    return acc
```

Test code, if someone else wanted to try to optimize:

```
@line_profiler_pycharm.profile
def main():
    N = 10_000_000
    A = np.random.random(N)

    # setting 50% nans
    A[np.random.choice(np.arange(N), N//2, replace=False)] = np.nan
    lb = np.random.random(N)
    ub = lb + np.random.random(N)

    # compiling
    do_sum(A, lb, ub)
    do_sum2(A, lb, ub)

    # test
    result1 = do_sum(A, lb, ub)
    result2 = do_sum2(A, lb, ub)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the work. But it is kind of in another direction than I expected. The real world use case for this function is like the lengths of those vectors are in thousands or tens of thousands at most and it is expected to be called millions of times. Not that dimension is super large and just call a few times. I should mention it in the original post but did not do that for simplicity. I added that info in my post anyway for super clarity.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, for not super large vectors, parallel=True significantly slows down the running time.

Comment: Eh, thats the problem when you do not provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Keptain Try doing multiprocessing somewhere "above" in the code hierarchy then. I am out of ideas. All this sounds like a task for GPU though